# mysql: how to get the FIRST 'StartAddress' and the LAST 'StopAddress'

Tags: mysql

I please need your help with the following code. Thanks in advance!

The query below works fine, but I'm unable to solve the following 2 problems.

**Problem 1:** LINE 6 below - I need code at line 6 to give me the StartAddress where StartAddress = MIN(SamplingStart) - it must be grouped the same way the others are grouped. eg. Min(SamplingStart) AS StartTime

**Problem 2:** LINE 7 below - I need code to give me the StopAddress where StopAddress = Max(SamplingEnd)

```
SELECT
ApplicationID,
MIN(SamplingStart) AS StartTime,
MAX(SamplingEnd) AS StopTime,
SUM(Duration) AS MDuration,
StartAddress AS StartAddress,  //PROBLEM 1
StopAddress AS StopAddress,    //PROBLEM 2
MIN(StartHours) AS StartHours,
MAX(EndHours) AS EndHours,
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(SamplingEnd),MIN(SamplingStart))) AS OTime,
Name,
UserID

FROM QEventReport
GROUP BY 
UserID,
Name,
DATE(DATE_ADD(SamplingStart, INTERVAL [_UTCOFFSET] SECOND))
ORDER BY DATE(SamplingStart), UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with only this kind of GROUP BY.

You need to change to use subquery or JOIN to get your expected result.